# NSButton not masking to bounds

Tags: swift, nsbutton

I am transferring an app for iOS to a toolbar app in OSX. Although I am using swift, the objects are rather different. I am having one major problem, however, that I cannot seem to overcome.

The code below produces the NSButton shown, but I cannot get rid of the grey background. masktobound has no effect. I have tried masking each corner individually, no effect. I just want a simple round button.

I also have several buttons with rounded corners, however these also show the light grey background.

Any pointers? Sample code would be appreciated.

[image: circular button, code below]

```
let connectButton = NSButton.init(title: NSLocalizedString(" ", comment: "OnButtonAccessibility"), target: self, action: #selector(toggle))
connectButton.wantsLayer = true
connectButton.isBordered = false
connectButton.layer?.masksToBounds=true
if #available(OSX 10.13, *) {
  connectButton.layer?.maskedCorners=[.layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
} else {

connectButton.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
connectButton.layer?.cornerRadius=80
connectButton.layer?.borderColor=DarkerBlue.cgColor
connectButton.layer?.borderWidth=3
(connectButton.cell as! NSButtonCell).isBordered=false
(connectButton.cell as! NSButtonCell).backgroundColor=NSColor.clear
connectButton.isTransparent=true
connectButton.frame=CGRect(x: 80, y: self.view.frame.size.height-260, width: 160, height: 160)
connectButton.tag=1002
self.view.addSubview(connectButton)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you must at least touch the NSButton.cell to have it conform to the button style. The backgroundstyle used seems to make no difference is you have the button filled or containing an image.

```
connectButton.cell?.backgroundStyle=NSView.BackgroundStyle.dark
```

Comment: This code doesn't work at all now. Probably Apple changed something.